# DynamoDB load nil Error

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to load my data from dynamoBD and print them out with the labels. 
Following the sample: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/DynamoDBObjectMapper-Sample
I already created a table on the account and I can see their attributes using web browser.
Using this code to load data:

```
var tableRow: DDBTableRow?
func getTableRow() {
    let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()

    dynamoDBObjectMapper .load(DDBTableRow.self, hashKey: (tableRow?.PhotoId)!, rangeKey: tableRow?.UserId) .continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), block: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        if let error = task.error as? NSError {
            print("Error: \(error)")
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Failed to get item from table.", message: error.description, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if let tableRow = task.result as? DDBTableRow {
            self.photoIdLabel.text = tableRow.PhotoId
            self.userIdLabel.text = tableRow.UserId
            self.photoDateLabel.text = tableRow.PhotoDate
            self.photoURLLabel.text = tableRow.PhotoURL
            self.photoCategoryLabel.text = tableRow.PhotoCategory
        }

        return nil
    })
}
```

In the log: tableRows   [MyProject.DDBTableRow]?    nil none.

The sample code is working fine, I don't know what wrong. Do I miss something before calling load? I feel very close to solve it. Please help!

Comment: I found the problem. There is tableRows:Array<DDBTableRow>. What I need to do is assigned this : for tableRow in self.tableRows! { //do the loading here// }